# conecting my ps to my tv using ethernet

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, router, ethernet

i am trying to connect my tv to the internet, my pc receives a wifi signal via my neighbours router and i am wanting to send that signal via my pc's ethernet port to my tv using an ethernet cable. my tv does not have a wifi reciever just an ethernet conection, so is this possible to do?? ie turning my pc into a router and sending the signal out through the ethernet port in the back of the pc?

Comment: Select your adapters and make a bridge (Bridged network).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that’s possible. Open the “Network and Sharing Center”, select “Change adapter settings” (on the left). In the view that comes up now, select both your wired and wireless connection, right-click on one of them and select “Bridge Connections”.

A guide with pictures is also available [here](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/create-a-network-bridge-windows).

Comment: hi thanks for your reply, i have tried this but it still isnt working, any ideas??

Comment: Could you clarify what exactly isn’t working? Go to your TV’s network diagnostic screen and check whether it gets an IP address. Is internet access still possible from your PC?

Comment: well im still connected now as im talking to you, but usually where it shows the bars of your signal strength, there is a cross, but when i click on it its saying i am still connected??

Comment: Look at your network setting on tv.

Comment: it just shows the status and says its not working, its saying that the ethernet cable isnt connected properly, but iv checked and it deffo is, it is also a brand new cable as it got delivered this morning,so should be working fine. on the status screen on the tv where it says ip address and proxy and things like that, there is nothing on there??

Comment: Look also at this one: [link](http://www.wikihow.com/Bridge-an-Internet-Connection)

Comment: Ok. is that a patch or an crossover cable. there is a little difference. So it could be also an cable issue. u need a crossover cable from pc to tv, if your network card can not crossover the cable by herself.

Comment: your tv should communicate with your pc at the right way. This is the first thing to do. If you just bridge the network, that do not work, nothing will work.

Comment: the ethernet cable is one of those 5e ones??

Comment: its a belkin cat5e networking cable rj45??

Comment: ok so iv checked the cable and it is working,i tried that link you gave me to bridge the connections, and followed it step by step, and when i get to the bit where i gotta type in th ip addresses in the local area conection, it doesnt give me the options in properties to type them in :/ ???? im confussed lol